# Compiling SASS in ExpressJS vs Grunt

Tags: express, sass, gruntjs, middleware

I know you can compile SASS in a ExpressJS app via code like

```
app.use(
    sass.middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/sass',
        dest: __dirname + '/public',
        debug: true
    })
);
```

but why would one choose this method instead of compiling SASS with GruntJS? Are there any advantages?

Answer (score 0):

So when you start you server, node-sass will see if the .css file in the dest file path has changed.  If it has, then it will compile the .scss file in the src file path.

Using grunt or gulp will allow you to not only compile scss to css, but also compile coffeescript to js and compress json, html, ect.  Moreover, you can initialize these actions upon any saved changes to the filepath specified in the grunt or gulp file.  So you can get a live reload on your browser when changes happen to any of these file types.

To do this, run your node server and in another tab, run your grunt / gulp process.